# Show that W is a subspace of $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let A be a 2 × 3 matrix and let W be the set of vectors x for which both of the entries of Ax are the same. Show that W is a subspace of $R^3$.

I just need some help initially setting this up. I know how to check the zero vector, but I need help with proving its closure under addition and multiplication.

Comment: The quick approach is to note that $W$ is the nullspace of the $1 \times 3$ matrix $[\;1 \quad -1\;]\;A$

Answer (score 1):

For additive closure, you want to start with

"Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be in $W$.  Then, by definition, $Wx_1 = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ a \end{bmatrix}$ and $Wx_2 = \begin{bmatrix} b \\ b \end{bmatrix}$ for some numbers $a$ and $b$."

And you'll end with

"Thus, by definition, $x_1+x_2$ is in $W$."

Try to fill in the missing details.  You'll then do the same thing for multiplicative closure.  Start with

"Let $x_1$ be in $W$ and $k$ be a real number.  Then, by definition, $Wx_1 = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ a \end{bmatrix}$  for some real numbers $a$."

And you'll end with

"Thus, by definition, $kx_1$ is in $W$."

Comment: To add on: Linearity gives $W(x_1+x_2)=W(x_1)+W(x_2)$ and for $c\in\mathbb{R}$, $W(cx_1)=cW(x_1)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c\\d&e&f
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $\vec x_1=[x_1,y_1,z_1]^T$,  $\vec x_2=[x_2,y_2,z_2]^T$ two vectors in $W$, so that we have: 
$$
A\vec x_1=\begin{bmatrix}
ax_1+by_1+cz_1\\dx_1+ey_1+fz_1
\end{bmatrix} \in W
\quad \mbox{and} \quad
A\vec x_2=\begin{bmatrix}
ax_2+by_2+cz_2\\dx_2+ey_2+fz_2
\end{bmatrix} \in W
$$
This means that :
$$
ax_1+by_1+cz_1=dx_1+ey_1+fz_1 \quad \iff \quad (a-d)x_1+(b-e)y_1+(c-f)z_1=0
$$

and
$$
ax_2+by_2+cz_2=dx_2+ey_2+fz_2 \quad \iff \quad (a-d)x_2+(b-e)y_2+(c-f)z_2=0
$$

so we have ( ''adding'' the two equations):
$$
(a-d)(x_1+x_2)+(b-e)(y_1+y_2)+(c-f)(z_1+z_2)=0
$$
and this means that $\vec x_1 + \vec x_2$ is an element of $W$.

In a similar way you can prove that $\lambda\vec x_1 \in W$